# Disconnect the database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails data mining app, and I would like to be able to do powerful demonstrations without a complicated user-interface.

Is there any way I can make a ruby console for the web that doesn't run the risk of say...

`User.destroy_all`
?

Something where I can call

```
ActiveRecord.disconnect!    
unsafe_actions
ActiveRecord.connect!
```

But where I could also have read priviledges (select, inner join, etc.)

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: One way might be use `remove_connection` and `establish_connection` to reconnect with a different user name which is configured in the DB to have read-only access. Perform the "unsafe_actions", and then go back using `remove_connection` and `establish_connection` again.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. But you could parse the input before actually running the script...

Comment: @mbratch that sounds like a solution. If you write up a rails-way of doing that that supports heroku I will surely accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can run the rails console in sandbox mode:

```
rails console --sandbox
```

or

```
rails c -s
```

Any changes you make in sandbox mode will be rolled back upon exiting the console.

(And prefix with `heroku run` to run it on heroku.)